# Java web application database connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to make simple java web application using Servlets & JSP, with a simple database connection .
but I am reading about database connection and i found that there is some methods like Connection pool , JDBC Driver ...
I don't know what is the best way , please help
(I'm using eclipse)

Comment: The [tutorials on the Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) are always an excellent starting point. You can look into connection pools etc when you understand the fundamentals of JDBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A connection pool is a set of connections which are available for your application to use and eventually connect to the database. This set, which is of *limited* size (you can run out of connections) is made available to you by the database server.

On the other hand, the JDBC driver is a mechanism which Java provides so that Java applications can connect to databases.

I would recommend you take a look at [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_and_databases.html) introductory tutorial so that you can get yourself better acquainted with the part of software development.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Thin Type 4 Driver is the best for database connection .Below is the code for connection.Hope u'll find it useful and btw Welcome to JAVA  !!

```
Connection con=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:PortNo:SID","USER","PWD");

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: _Oracle Thin Type 4 Driver is the best for database connection_? What do you mean? What If I have a MySQL database? Seems to be nonsense...